# Paragraph overlapping images

Tags: html, css, image, paragraph

My english is bad, so i try you to explain my problem on the picture :)
My problem: [Click!](http://android.batarin.zp.ua/keddrreader/verstka.png)

My html:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<div class='videobox'>
  <img id='thumb' src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/ILw2sAT8mro/maxresdefault.jpg'>
    <img id='button' src='http://android.batarin.zp.ua/keddrreader/YouTube-icon-full_color.png'>
</div>
<p>Some text</p>
```

My css:

```
img{
  width: 100%;
}
.videobox{
  position: relative;
}
#thumb{
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}
#button{
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}
p{
  position: relative;
}
```

Can somebody help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the position of the button to be relative

```
#button{
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I'd do it the way any of the answers have suggested except for changing the button to `relative` so here's my answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/6a6q4/2/

Basically, give a height to the `videobox` div (it has zero height because of the absolute positioning).

```
.videobox{
    position: relative;
    height: 281px;
}
```

The `281px` is a bit of a magic number fix, I just used the height of the resized thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code from

```
#thumb{
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

to

```
#thumb{
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tanvir0604/6gdgZ/) link

Answer (score 0):

Because you are absolutely positioning items. You could add this CSS to your last `<p>` tag.

```
position: absolute;
top: 330px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `<p>` for child like this...

Here is your answer

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/79SCj/2/)

**CSS**

```
  p:last-child {
        position: relative;
        display: -webkit-box;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 60%;
         }
```

Also you can assign this code for all paragraph after image

**CSS**

```
#p{
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 60%;
}
```

[**HERE IS YOUR ANSWER**](http://jsfiddle.net/79SCj/5/)

Comment: it works but if another paragraph is added it will break again: http://jsfiddle.net/79SCj/4/

Comment: @martincarlin87 : yha, see i have assigned for last child of <p> , here in your example , you have given "oops" <p> as last child... :)